# How to compare variable with other variable with string value in conditional

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to make the following conditional work:

`when: (vnet_info.stdout|from_json).vnet.virtualnetworks[0].address_prefixes[1] != private_ipv6`

`private_ipv6` is a variable defined by me in the playbook. The problem is that the string value is being used in the conditional without quotes and throws an error. How to I surround it with quotes?

I tried:
`"{{private_ipv6}}"`:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '(vnet_info.stdout|from_json).vnet.virtualnetworks[0].address_prefixes[1] != \"{{ private_ipv6 }}\"' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if (vnet_info.stdout|from_json).vnet.virtualnetworks[0].address_prefixes[1] != \"fdda:e69b:2547:485e::/64\" %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): expected string or buffer\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ik/Playbooks/azure/wdicsetup.yml': line 47,column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - pause:\n      ^ here\n"}
```

`private_ipv6|str`

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '(vnet_info.stdout|from_json).vnet.virtualnetworks[0].address_prefixes[1] != private_ipv6|str' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: no filter named 'str'. String: {% if (vnet_info.stdout|from_json).vnet.virtualnetworks[0].address_prefixes[1] != private_ipv6|str %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ik/Playbooks/azure/wdicsetup.yml': line 47, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - pause:\n   ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it was another error and vnet_info was already containing json data. I should've used `net_info.virtualnetworks[0].address_prefixes[1] != private_ipv6`